# Spring boot does not render JSP pages, Spring boot new Versions (2.5.0)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jsp, model-view-controller

When I run an old project using Spring Boot 2.1.8 Release, it runs fine and all JSP files are displayed properly but recently I created a new project and using 2.5.0 Release (WAR, Java 11,
Embedded Tomcat). It does not render JSP files and doesn't show an error message as well !

**ApplicationConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "school.com.my.myschool")
public class ApplicationConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {

@Override
protected void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry){
    registry.addResourceHandler("css/**", "images/**")
            .addResourceLocations("classpath:static/css/", "classpath:static/images/");
}


@Bean
InternalResourceViewResolver jspViewResolver(){
    InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp");
    viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
    return viewResolver;
}
}
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven- 
4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
<version>2.5.0</version>
<relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>school.com.my</groupId>
<artifactId>myschool</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>myschool</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
         <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

</project>
```

*HomeController*

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

@GetMapping("/home")
public String toHome(){
    System.out.println("In Home Controller!");
    return "index";
}
}
```

**I Run it as -> Maven - Plugins - spring-boot - spring-boot-run**

When I run **http://localhost:8080/home**

*While label Error* Page **There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404)**

But in the Console ->

```
2021-06-16 12:48:22.087  INFO 4136 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2021-06-16 12:48:22.571  INFO 4136 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
2021-06-16 12:48:25.499  INFO 4136 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2021-06-16 12:48:25.605  INFO 4136 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2021-06-16 12:48:27.857  WARN 4136 --- [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2021-06-16 12:48:29.852  INFO 4136 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2021-06-16 12:48:29.933  INFO 4136 --- [           main] s.com.my.myschool.MyschoolApplication    : Started MyschoolApplication in 38.136 seconds (JVM running for 41.125)
2021-06-16 12:48:29.939  INFO 4136 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.ApplicationAvailabilityBean      : Application availability state LivenessState changed to CORRECT
2021-06-16 12:48:29.950  INFO 4136 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.ApplicationAvailabilityBean      : Application availability state ReadinessState changed to ACCEPTING_TRAFFIC
2021-06-16 12:48:37.223  INFO 4136 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2021-06-16 12:48:37.224  INFO 4136 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2021-06-16 12:48:37.232  INFO 4136 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 8 ms
In Home Controller!
```

**Folder Structure**

[image]

**Any Idea please ?**

Comment: can you share your folder structure?

Comment: @kameshsr just added it

Comment: By sub-classing `WebMvcConfigurationSupport` you are telling Spring Boot that you want to take complete control of Spring MVC’s configuration so Spring Boot’s auto-configuration backs off. That’s unlikely to be what you want. Generally speaking, you should implement `WebMvcConfigurer` instead. In fact, you’re duplicating parts of what Boot will do for you so I’d remove the code entirely and set the `spring.mvc.view.prefix` and `spring.mvc.view.suffix` properties instead.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson Thank you so much AndyWilkinson, you helped me a lot. I changed 'WebMvcConfigurationSupport' class to 'WebMvcConfigurer' interface and then I set the View Resolvers in **application.properties** and it worked well. But I do have a question that when can I use 'InternalResourceViewResolver' with the new Spring-Boot versions  ?

Answer (score 0):

Run by "tomcat".

I think you were run "Spring Boot application" in IDEA.

I failed same you.

Comment: Yes I use Intellij IDEA and Embedded Tomcat.  But at the comment section, @AndyWilkinson solved the problem.   Have you solved yours  ?

Comment: Yes I solved it. Thank you for your regardness :)